# How to dynamically populate data from url to expandable listview categories in android?

Tags: android

hiii,

I am working on a project where i am calling a url and fetching data as json . Now , this json object will be parsed.

Now i am getting a json tag like status= active or status = notActive.

Based on this response , i have to place some data tags which have a status "Active" under group title "Active" under listview and notActive data under "NOT-ACTIVE" group title.

**How to different data based on status value under two groups seperately so that when i click Active group , i will ge**t different data for Active only .

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way i solved it.

```
 try{




jArray = new JSONArray(json);



for(int i=0;i<jArray.length() ;i++){                        


     Map<String, String> childdata1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


        String status = e.getString("2");
        // Log.e("log_tag","Status: "+status); 

         if (status.contains("active")){
            // Log.e("log_tag","StatusActive: "+status); 

                //childdata1.put("child",   String.valueOf(i));

                childdata1.put("child", e.getString("mlsid"));
                childdata1.put("child1",  e.getString("status"));
                childdata1.put("child2", e.getString("address"));
                childdata1.put("child3",  e.getString("city"));


                child1.add(childdata1); 

         }else if(status.contains("pending")){
             //Log.e("log_tag","StatusPending: "+status); 



                Map<String, String> childdata2= new HashMap<String, String> ();
               // childdata2.put("0",  String.valueOf(i));
                childdata2.put("child", e.getString("mlsid"));
                childdata2.put("child1",  e.getString("status"));
                childdata2.put("child2", e.getString("address"));
                childdata2.put("child3",  e.getString("city"));

                child2.add(childdata2);




         }


    }   
// Log.e("log_tag","ARRAY Length : "+jArray.length()); 
  }catch(JSONException e)        {
 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
```